# Custom validation error during package installation with custom lightning app builder page template

Tags: aura, package-install, page-template

I created a Custom Lightning Page Template and used it in the App home page.
Aura cmp file appHomeTemplate.cmp:

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:homeTemplate" description="appHomeTemplate">
<aura:attribute name="header" type="Aura.Component[]"></aura:attribute>
<aura:attribute name="left" type="Aura.Component[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="right" type="Aura.Component[]"/>

<div>
    <lightning:layout>
        <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="grow" class="slds-m-bottom_small">
            {!v.header}
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>
    <lightning:layout>
        <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="grow"
                              class="slds-m-right_small slds-m-top_small">
            {!v.left}
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem size="{! $Browser.isDesktop ? '4' : '6' }"
                              class="slds-m-left_small slds-m-top_small">
            {!v.right}
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Aura design file appHomeTemplate.design:

```
<design:component>
<flexipage:template >
    <flexipage:region name="header" defaultWidth="LARGE" />
    <flexipage:region name="left" defaultWidth="MEDIUM">
        <flexipage:formfactor type="MEDIUM" width="SMALL" />
    </flexipage:region>
    <flexipage:region name="right" defaultWidth="SMALL" />
</flexipage:template>
</design:component>
```

Fragment of Home page metadata

```
    <masterLabel>Home Page Default</masterLabel>
    <template>
        <name>appHomeTemplate</name>
    </template>
    <type>HomePage</type>
```

When I tried to install package version with these changes I get an error:
There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "Template XXXX:appHomeTemplate doesn't exist.".
XXXX is package namespace.
Do you have any idea how to fix it? I tried "googling" but didn't find any information about it.